# Tradingview self hosted chart, custom study not found error

Tags: tradingview-api

I tried creating a custom study following this [doc](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/issues/3095). (You need to have access to the charting library to view that link)

But I'm still getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Was.png) script not found error.

Note: My script name matches the description name which is a different error with an resolution, so it's not about that.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @iomario maybe you know anything?